# What are prerequisites for integrating web application to skype web sdk business online

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

Mainly

- The list of dependencies needs to be installed in local system to start with development.

As a part of prerequisite I got to know below points to start with [skype web sdk - skype for business online](https://ucwa.skype.com)

Prerequisites :

```
 1. A tenant on Office 365 with a user who is assigned a Skype for Business license.
 2. Need to set up a tenant in Azure Active Directory.
```

Kindly help what exactly points mean and what I have to do to complete these two points ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need an Office 365 account license. And then you will have to create users. These are the users which will be able to access Skype For Business Online.
2. You need have an Azure Subscription. There you should have an Active Directory. This active directory should be synced with your OFiice 365 active directory. Meaning that the users should also be listed under your Azure Active Directory. This Azure Active Directory would be used to authenticate your app and the user. And log them into Skype For Business Online.

You can have a look. How to [Set everything up](http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2016/03/skype-web-sdk-online-setting-everything-up-step-by-step-guide/)

Comment: Thank you very much link is very useful

Comment: @SatishakumarAwati Welcome